# Getting type mismatch: inferred type is List but Collection was expected

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

Still stuck at this Breaking Bad API App. JSON model class is a list but when I'm calling the response in the global scope and putting it the mutable list it says type mismatch: inferred type is List  but Collection was expected. How can i fix it

Main Activity

```
> class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
> 
>     private lateinit var characterAdapter : MyAdapter
>     private var TAG = "MainActivity"
>     private var characterData= mutableListOf<ResponseBBItem>()
>     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
> 
>         characterAdapter = MyAdapter(characterData , this)
>         recyclerView.adapter = characterAdapter
>         val layoutMAnager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
>         recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutMAnager
>         getCharacterInfo()
> 
>         recyclerView.setOnClickListener {
>             getCharacterInfo()
>         }
>     }
> 
>     private fun getCharacterInfo() {
>         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
>             try {
>                 val response = Client.api.getInfo()
>                 if (response.isSuccessful) {
>                    val characterList = response.body()
>                     Log.d(TAG, characterData.toString())
>                     withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
>                         if (characterList!= null) {
>                             Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity , "Data Loaded"

    enter code here

,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
>                             characterData.addAll(characterList.responseBB!!)
>                             characterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
>                             tvText.text = characterList.toString()
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (e:Exception){
>                 withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
>                     Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Cannot Load Data" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     } }
```

I'm getting the error at `characterData.addAll(characterList.responseBB!!)`

APIRequest

```
interface APIRequest {

    @GET("character/random")

    suspend fun getInfo() : Response<ResponseBB>
}
```

ResponseBB

```
data class ResponseBB(

    @field:SerializedName("ResponseBB")
    val responseBB: List<ResponseBBItem?>? = null
)
```

I believe that 2 ?s in `List<ResponseBBItem?>?`are giving me error

ResponseBBItem

```
data class ResponseBBItem(

    @field:SerializedName("birthday")
    val birthday: Any? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("img")
    val img: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("better_call_saul_appearance")
    val betterCallSaulAppearance: Any? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("occupation")
    val occupation: List<String?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("appearance")
    val appearance: List<Int?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("portrayed")
    val portrayed: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("nickname")
    val nickname: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("char_id")
    val charId: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("category")
    val category: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status")
    val status: String? = null
)
```

Client

```
object Client {

    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()

    val  api = retrofit.create(APIRequest::class.java)
}
```

MyAdapter

```
class MyAdapter(var listChar : List<ResponseBBItem?>, val context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
        var occupation = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOccupation)
        var protrayed = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvActor)
        var status = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvStatus)
        var appearance = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAppearance)
        var image = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivImage)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent , false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
       holder.appearance.text = listChar[position]!!.appearance.toString()
        holder.name.text = listChar[position]!!.name
        holder.occupation.text = listChar[position]!!.occupation.toString()
        holder.protrayed.text = listChar[position]!!.portrayed
        holder.status.text = listChar[position]!!.status
        Picasso.get().load(listChar[position]!!.img).into(holder.image)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listChar.size

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you’re trying to put a `List<ResponseBBItem?>` into a `MutableList<ResponseBBItem>`. Since the MutableList can only hold non-null ResponseBBItem, it won’t accept your collection of nullable ResponseBBItem. Either change the type of the mutable list to be nullable, call `filterNonNull()` on the list you pass to `addAll()` or change `reaponseBB` to return `List<ResponseBBItem>`.

Comment: API call don't run if I change the List<ResponseBBItem>. How can make the mutable list nullable?

Comment: You don't want to make the MutableList nullable, only the type that goes in it. You do that by putting a question mark after the type: `private var characterData= mutableListOf<ResponseBBItem?>()` However, it is quite unlikely this is the solution you should want to take, because then you have to deal with null items in the list. Most likely the best solution would be filtering out the null values: `characterData.addAll(characterList.responseBB?.filterNotNull() ?: emptyList())`

Comment: By the way, if you are just beginning with Kotlin, using `!!` is almost certainly wrong every time you do it. There is a very narrow set of situations where it is appropriate to use it at all, so if you feel tempted to use it, I suggest you read more about what nullability means: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: Tenfour04 If I do private var characterData= mutableListOf<ResponseBBItem?>() then API doesn't work

Comment: ??? That property has nothing to do with the API. You'll have to define "doesn't work".

Comment: Tenfour04 I mean if I use haracterData= mutableListOf<ResponseBBItem?>() , Retrofit gives the exception case of the try and catch block

Comment: I don’t see where you are passing `characterData` to Retrofit. What is the exception thrown? And like I said, this is probably not the right solution. Probably the right solution is filtering nulls out of the data.